# USB-C monitor stopped working after LUKS install

Tags: linux, debian, usb, uefi, multi-monitor

I have two monitors, and was using them daisy-chained over USB-C thunderbolt on an Intel NUC8i5BEH. I recently reformatted to use full disk encryption (using LUKS via Debian installer).

Everything seemed fine on the first boot, but after I powered off I've only been able to get the USB-C monitor working erratically (and not at all lately). The monitor consistently goes dark just before the LUKS password prompt, and never turns back on again.

Some facts:

- The monitor works during BIOS, but goes dark at the LUKS password prompt.
- HDMI video works fine.
- Devices connected to the in-monitor USB hub work fine.
- I got the monitor working once, but after unplugging it, it stopped for good. I don't know what I did.
- I changed my boot mode to "Legacy" in the bios to get LUKS working.
- The monitor works if I set `nomodeset` on startup, but if I do this with my second monitor attached via HDMI, `xrandr` only shows a single display and both screens show the same content.
- Also, pressing `ctrl+alt+f1` to get to a terminal freezes the computer when I boot with `nomodeset`.

I'm at a loss as to how to debug this! If anyone can point me at a place to start I'd be deeply grateful! I miss having two monitors!

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable a feature called "Thunderbolt BIOS Assist Mode" in your BIOS. The exact name and location may vary between brands and models, but in essence, when Secure Boot/UEFI is disable, the initramfs now needs a "push" from the BIOS to connect with the Thunderbolt controller. There may be more than one feature available under the same tab.

Comment: Thanks! This is really helpful. I've gone through all the Thunderbolt options in my BIOS, and there's nothing on point (I tried all reasonable permutations, and updated the BIOS).

So I think my next step is to try migrating to UEFI. I'm pretty sure it can be done, but it seemed messy, so I didn't want to try without some indication it would fix the problem. It sounds as if that's exactly what I need though. I'll report back!

Comment: It took a few hours, but I'm now booting from UEFI (with legacy boot disabled), but I'm still not able to get the monitor working. Interestingly, on my first boot after enabling UEFI, the thunderbolt monitor worked, so I thought my problem was fixed, but since rebooting, nothing =(.